# Can I make a copy of a scanner?

Tags: java, methods, parameters

I have a method that takes a scanner in as a parameter and I would like to copy it so I can use it twice.  Is that possible?

I'm sorry I'm new to this website.  Is this an all java website? because thats what I'm using.

Comment: To answer your second question, it is by no means an all java website. But to reach people who know stuff about java, simply tag your post with "java" and whatever else applies to your question and it'll be easier for people who know java to find it.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know if you want to use it twice either you have to initialize two scanners or initialize the same scanner when you process it for the first time. 
So the overall answer for this question is that intialize again the scanner when you processed the stream for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you mean by "... so I can use it twice".

The fatuous interpretation is that you want to make more than one call on the `Scanner` object.  Obviously, you don't meed to copy the `Scanner` to do that.

The next interpretation is that you want to use `Scanner`s to read the same token stream twice from the same input stream.  That won't work.  A scanner assumes that it has exclusive use of the underlying input stream ... and it *consumes* the characters from the stream.  So if you have one input stream with two scanners, one of your scanners will get some of the input characters, and the other will get the rest.  (And furthermore, which scanner gets which characters is not going to be easily predictable.)

There are a few ways ways around this though.  For example -

- If the data source is a file (that your application opens), you can open it twice and create two independent `Scanner`s for it.
- You could read the entire stream into memory as a String or StringBuffer or character array, and then create two input streams to read the buffered data, and inpdependent `Scanner`s for the streams.
- You could use a "tee stream" (for example: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/TeeInputStream.html) or similar to save a copy of the input to a separate output stream, then feed the data written to the latter to a separate Scanner.

The final interpretation is that you want two Scanners that return tokens from the same stream.  If you want to do that, you are better of using one Scanner, and passing it to the two places that need it.  (If you try to use two scanners on the same input stream, you are liable to run into the problems mentioned above.)